# Codeigniter 2 silent error on shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, shared-hosting

**index.php**

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mirror.example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

The hosting provider use PHP version 5.3. But I can't see anything including errors. I wonder is anybody here ever feel the same experience ?

What's wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Try error_reporting(E_ALL) in the top of the function specifically in the controller and check.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a server configuration problem
maybe is the directive "disable_functions" for ini_set active
do you have access to the php.ini ?

if not ask your provider

additional information:

i don't see a problem in your configuration
maybe you can try to add the following:

```
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;
```

Comment: Ok I will ask this to the provider. is there any other posibbilities regarding to this error?

Comment: i don't see a problem with your way, but for the sake of hope, i added the version which i use in all projects in my answer (i never got problems with that one)

Comment: I have add it now its still loading

Comment: what do you mean with "it's still loading"?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is not the server, but coding style compatibility issue:

I use this (*not support by PHP 5.3*)

```
$this->data['current_user'] = $this->user->get_by(array(
'id' => $this->session->userdata('user_session')['user_id']
));
```

Instead of:

```
$user_session = $this->session->userdata('user_session');

$this->data['current_user'] = $this->user->get_by(array(
'id' => $user_session['user_id']
));
```

Thanks everyone :)